# How can I count current indexing inside a loop?

Tags: craft3

Is it Possible to count current indexing in a loop which starts from indexing 1 as well as 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig offers special loop variables that makes it easy to know indexing of a loop.
You can use loop.index to count your current indexing of the loop, which will starting at 1.
If You want to start your indexing from 0 so simply add 0 after loop.index like loop.index0.

There are other loop variable as well.

Like:

- loop.revindex
- loop.revindex0
- loop.first
- loop.last
- loop.length

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the documentation on Craft web site https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/twig-primer.html, Twig is documented in its own site: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/

ZealousWeb's answer is documented here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html

> Inside of a for loop block you can access some special variables:
>
> - loop.index The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)|
> - loop.index0  The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)
> - loop.revindex   The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1 indexed)
> - loop.revindex0  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0 indexed)
> - loop.first  True if first iteration
> - loop.last   True if last iteration
> - loop.length     The number of items in the sequence
> - loop.parent     The parent context
>
> ```
> {% for user in users %}
>    {{ loop.index }} - {{ user.username }}
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> The loop.length, loop.revindex, loop.revindex0, and loop.last variables are only available for PHP arrays, or objects that implement the Countable interface.